# Facebook Graph API comments filtering not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, filtering

I need to filter out a specific comment by its id using the post thread. I have tried these processes but failed.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{post_id}?fields=message,comments&filtering=[{'field':'id','operator':'IN','value':[{comment_id}]}]&access_token`

returns all comments

`https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/103436852373094_146018341448278?fields=message,comments{id,message&filtering=[{'field':'id','operator':'IN','value':[{comment_id}]}]}`

returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Syntax error \"Expected \"}\", got end of string\" at character 27: message,comments{id,message",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "ASHThq8rIMxJztBRcwWS-I2
"
  }
}
```

did I missed anything?

Comment: Apart from the messed-up syntax - what makes you think that filtering comments this way was possible in the first place?

Comment: maybe I am wrong and my query too. can you please guide? @CBroe

Comment: I don't see the docs mention anywhere that _this_ kind of filtering on comments was possible.